# There is a diff between parenthesis $() and curly bracket ${} syntax in Makefile. But I don't know why

Tags: makefile

First version of my makefile

```
func:
    $(call exec-on-changed-file, "$$(DIR)")

define exec-on-changed-file
    DIR=GOOD;echo $(1)
endef
```

I exec it and it doesn't work

```
$ make func
DIR=GOOD;echo  "$(DIR)"
/bin/sh: 1: DIR: not found
```

I make a change on this makefile (parenthesis vs bracket)

```
func:
    $(call exec-on-changed-file, "$${DIR}")

define exec-on-changed-file
    DIR=GOOD;echo $(1)
endef
```

I exec it and it works.

```
$ make func
DIR=GOOD;echo  "${DIR}"
GOOD
```

Could you explain to me why ?

Comment: When you put a text inside quotation marks, it interprets it as a BASH variable, when not put, interprets it as a make variable.

Comment: @Rolbrok that's not true.  Make doesn't care about quotes in any way: it treats them the same as `a` or `b` etc.  The reason it's interpreted by bash not make is not the quotes, but because the dollar sign is escaped `$$`.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry for the misinformation. Thank you though.

Answer (score 6):

As your output shows, when you use `$$(DIR)`,
the shell sees `$(DIR)`, which is a valid shell syntax for running the *command* `DIR`, which doesn't exist.

When you use `$${DIR}`, the shell sees `${DIR}`, which is a valid shell syntax for the *variable* `DIR`.

The `$$` in the `call` expands to `$`.